# how to adjust the width of a node with variable text

Tags: tikz-pgf, width

I would like to create an environment for my definitions or properties, like that:

[image]

```
\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix [anchor=west,inner xsep=0pt] at (0,0)
    {
    \node
        [text width=4cm,inner xsep=0ex,inner ysep=1ex,text=Maroon,fill=Tan] (titre)
        {\quad {Définition 1} : a long title }; \\
    \node
        [anchor=north west,fill=white!40!Tan,draw=none,text justified,inner xsep=1em, inner ysep=1em,
        text width=\columnwidth-2em-1pt,text=Maroon] (texte)
        {some text} ;\\
    };
    \draw [line width=1pt, color=Maroon,rounded corners=5pt](titre.south west)--(titre.north west)--(titre.north east)--(titre.south east);
    \draw [line width=1pt, color=Maroon,rounded corners=0pt](titre.south east)--(texte.north east)--(texte.south east)--
    (texte.south east)--(texte.south west)--(titre.south west);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

and I want to adjust the width of the first node to the width of the title, because something like that happens with long title :

[image]

I tried with the `\widthof` command, the `\def` command, the `width` option inside tikz ... anyway, nothing works. My environment is this one :

```
\newcounter{definition}
\NewEnviron{definition}[1]{
\stepcounter{definition}
\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm, scale=1, every node/.style={scale=1}]
\matrix [anchor=west,inner xsep=0pt] at (0,0)
    {
    \node
        [text width={width("\quad \textbf{Définition} \thedefinition #1")},inner xsep=0ex,inner ysep=1ex,text=Maroon,fill=Tan] (titre)
        {\quad \textbf{Définition} \thedefinition\ #1}; \\
    \node
        [anchor=north west,fill=white!40!Tan,draw=none,text justified,inner xsep=1em, inner ysep=1em,
        text width=\columnwidth-2em-1pt,text=Maroon] (texte)
        {\BODY};
    };
    \draw [line width=1pt, color=Maroon,rounded corners=5pt](titre.south west)--(titre.north west)--(titre.north east)--(titre.south east);
    \draw [line width=1pt, color=Maroon,rounded corners=0pt](titre.south east)--(texte.north east)--(texte.south east)--
    (texte.south east)--(texte.south west)--(titre.south west);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What happens if you don't specify the `text width` at all?

Comment: Do you know [`tcolorbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox)?

Comment: yes I know (a little bit) this package ... but I would like to know how to do what I need here. I try the first solution, it seems to be good but I have errors with the `newenvironment`. I try to figure it out.

Comment: ok, it's perfect without specifying `text width`. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although, it seems that OP is not interested in a `tcolorbox` version for this format, may be someone else want it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{
    defstyle/.style={
        enhanced, 
        colback=Tan!40, 
        colbacktitle=Tan, 
        colframe=Maroon, 
        colupper=Maroon, 
        coltitle=Maroon,
        sharp corners, 
        attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-.5mm}, 
        boxed title style={
            skin=enhancedfirst jigsaw,
            boxrule=.5mm,
            bottom=-.5mm}, 
        }
    }

\newtcbtheorem{Definition}{Définition}{defstyle}{def}

\begin{document}

\begin{Definition}{My title}{}
Some text
\end{Definition}

\begin{Definition}{This is a longer title}{}
Some text
\end{Definition}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: yes, that's I have now in a different way. That's very interesting with this solution. Thanks a lot. I'll try it with tikz pictures inside, to see if this box doesn't deform the picture (I have to use `\savebox` `\usebox` for this at this time).

Comment: @Stan Please, take a look a [`tcolorbox` documentation](http://texdoc.net/pkg/tcolorbox) and you will see how you can draw any `tikzpicture` inside a `tcolorbox` and you don't have to use `\savebox` and `\usebox`. In any case if you explain this "new problem", may be we can help ;-)

Comment: Thank you. I knew tcolorbox but I didn't have "so much time" to learn about it (I spent time with tikz). But I'm going to read the book now (p150 at this time ;-)  ). It's working fine with my tikz picture too. That's a great solution.